# Button inside listview clickable after few seconds

Tags: android, listview

I have created listview with sr,name,button and timer(textview).I want button must be clickable only after countdown is over.Problem is that button is clickable even if countdown is going on.The button must not get clicked until time gets over.
Following is my code-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnnext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnnext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {

    int sr;
    String name;
    long expirationTime;

    public Model(int sr, String name,long expirationTime) {
        this.sr = sr;
        this.name = name;
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    }


    public int getSr() {
        return sr;
    }

    public void setSr(int sr) {
        this.sr = sr;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getExpirationTime() {
        return expirationTime;
    }

    public void setExpirationTime(long expirationTime) {
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    }
}
```

**Second.java**

```
public class Second extends Activity{

TextView txtsrno,txtflower,txtstatus,txttimer,txttimeleft;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Model> flowerlist;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        txtsrno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srno);
        txtflower = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buy);
        txttimeleft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.remtime);






                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                flowerlist = new ArrayList<>();

                flowerlist.add(new Model(1, "Rose",System.currentTimeMillis() + 100000));
                flowerlist.add(new Model(2, "Sunflower",System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000));
                flowerlist.add(new Model(3, "Lotus",System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000));
                flowerlist.add(new Model(4, "Jasmine",System.currentTimeMillis() + 20000));

                SecondCustom sc = new SecondCustom(this, flowerlist);
                listView.setAdapter(sc);


            }
}
```

**SecondCustom.java**

```
public class SecondCustom extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity a;
    ArrayList<Model> flowerlist;
    private List<Viewholder> lstHolders;
    long timeDiff;


    private LayoutInflater lf;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (Viewholder holder : lstHolders) {
                    holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
                }
            }
        }
    };



    public SecondCustom(Activity a, ArrayList<Model> flowerlist) {
        this.a = a;
        this.flowerlist = flowerlist;
        lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
        startUpdateTimer();
    }


    private void startUpdateTimer() {
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flowerlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return flowerlist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public class Viewholder{
        TextView srno,name,ltime;
        Button buy;
        Model mModel;


        public void setData(Model item) {
            mModel = item;
            name.setText(item.name);
            updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
            long timeDiff = mModel.expirationTime - currentTime;
            if (timeDiff > 0) {
                int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
                int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                ltime.setText(hours +":" + minutes +":" + seconds);

            } else {

                ltime.setText("Buy Now!!");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       Viewholder viewholder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.secondcustom, viewGroup, false);
            viewholder.srno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sr);
            viewholder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flow);
            viewholder.buy = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.st);
            viewholder.ltime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lefttime);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                lstHolders.add(viewholder);
            }
        }else {
                viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewholder.setData((Model) getItem(i));


            final Model model=flowerlist.get(i);
        viewholder.srno.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getSr()));
        viewholder.name.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getName()));
        viewholder.ltime.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getExpirationTime()));



            if(timeDiff==0) {
                viewholder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(a, "Purchased" + " " + flowerlist.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: use view.onclicklistener as it is, just when timer is running call view.setclickable(false) and after timer stops call view.setclickable(true)

Comment: how to implement that code?Can u give me exact code plz.

Comment: you want to click button when timeDiff became 0 right?

Comment: yes when timer gets stop.Button must get clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change this method:

```
public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
            long timeDiff = mModel.expirationTime - currentTime;
            if (timeDiff > 0) {
                int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
                int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                ltime.setText(hours +":" + minutes +":" + seconds);

                buy.set.setClickable(false);

            } else {
                buy.set.setClickable(true);
                ltime.setText("Buy Now!!");
            }
        }
```

And at this code, remove if condition just call click listener:

```
if(timeDiff==0) {
                viewholder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(a, "Purchased" + " " + flowerlist.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
public class Viewholder{
        TextView srno,name,ltime;
        Button buy;
        Model mModel;


        public void setData(Model item) {
            mModel = item;
            name.setText(item.name);
            updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
            timeDiff = mModel.expirationTime - currentTime; // Changes -- remove long
            if (timeDiff > 0) {
                int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
                int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                ltime.setText(hours +":" + minutes +":" + seconds);

            } else {

                ltime.setText("Buy Now!!");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       Viewholder viewholder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.secondcustom, viewGroup, false);
            viewholder.srno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sr);
            viewholder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flow);
            viewholder.buy = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.st);
            viewholder.ltime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lefttime);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                lstHolders.add(viewholder);
            }
        }else {
                viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewholder.setData((Model) getItem(i));


            final Model model=flowerlist.get(i);
        viewholder.srno.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getSr()));
        viewholder.name.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getName()));
        viewholder.ltime.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getExpirationTime()));

if(timeDiff!=0) {
viewholder.buy.setclickable(false);
viewholder.buy.setEnabled(false); 
}else{
viewholder.buy.setclickable(true);
viewholder.buy.setEnabled(true); 
}

                viewholder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(a, "Purchased" + " " + flowerlist.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });



        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: its showing error at setclickable as cannot resolve method setclickable(boolean).

Comment: `setClickable(boolean)` use this

Answer (score 0):

Try to move click listener code out side if condition and you need to just set Button clickable and enable true/false based on timer value as below :

```
viewholder.buy.setClickable(timeDiff==0);
viewholder.buy.setEnabled(timeDiff==0);

viewholder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
       Toast.makeText(a, "Purchased" + " " + flowerlist.get(i).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
```